# Trying to return a variable outside of a function

Tags: javascript

I am pretty sure I am doing this wrong but what I want to happen is onload i want function test to run then function one then function two, and then I want function two to return var abc from function one.

```
window.onload=function(){
  test();
};

function test(){
    var abc;
  function one(){
    abc = 1;
    two();
  }
  function two(){
    console.log(abc);
  }

}
```

Comment: It's a pain to read your question. Try to split it to sentences. Also, how do you suppose function *two* can return value from function *one*? Finally, I don't see any `return` keywords in whole listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only declared function `one` you need to executed it. At the end of the `test` function add `one();` see below:

```
window.onload=function(){
    test();
};

function test(){
    var abc;
    function one(){
        abc = 1;
        two();
    }
    function two(){
        console.log(abc);
    }
    one();//execute function 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> i want function test to run then function one

That's the step you were missing. Your `test` function currently only declares `function one`, but never calls it.

```
function test() {
    var abc;
    function one() {
        abc = 1;
        two();
    }
    function two() {
        console.log(abc);
    }
    one(); // call it!
}
test(); // logs 1
```

There might be better ways to share values between functions than closure (depending on the use case), but this does what you want.